# How to use setImageUri() on Android

Tags: android, uri, imagebutton

Can you help me please? I've tried :

```
ImageButton imgbt=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbutton);
Uri imgUri=Uri.parse("/data/data/MYFOLDER/myimage.png");
imgbt.setImageUri(imgUri);
```

but I didn't see anything, simply a void button.

Comment: Do you need to load the image specifically from a location on disk (like an SD card) or are you fine with loading it as a resource from R?

Comment: Maybe you need to prepend `file://`

Answer (score 18):

ImageView.setImageUri only works for local Uri, ie a reference to a local disk file, not a URL to an image on the network.

Here is an example of how to fetch a Bitmap from the network.

```
    private Bitmap getImageBitmap(String url) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            URL aURL = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           Log.e(TAG, "Error getting bitmap", e);
       }
       return bm;
    }
```

Once you have the Bitmap from getImageBitmap(), use:  imgView.setImageBitmap(bm);

Comment: thanks, this `getImageBitmap` method works for me. Far better than using `setImageURI`

Comment: @iredelweb should really approve this answer.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, about how to make .setImageUri to work.  It just shows how to read a bitmap from the network.  How does that make an image appear in an ImageView ?

Answer (score 8):

It should be

```
Uri imgUri=Uri.parse("file:///data/data/MYFOLDER/myimage.png");
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this one:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fullFileName);
imgProfileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 2):

Its best to avoid building the path by hand, try :

```
imgbt.setImageUri(Uri.fromFile(new File("/data/data/....")));
```

Answer (score 1):

I also met this issue, it did not show anything.
I saw something like this in android developer. It didn't use setImageURI.

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri, Context context) throws IOException {
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
            context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
    return image;
}
```

Just for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String imgPath = Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/com.wariyum.signage/files/"+ "221215-085656.619.72.jpg";

    //Following lines was expected work, but don't really show up image always - no idea why
    //imgZoom.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imgPath)); 

    //following works always perfectly
            File imgFile = new  File(imgPath);
            if(imgFile.exists()){
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                imgZoom.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with framework. Added this line into the gradle:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.8.0'
```

Init singlton in application-class(or another main class in your app)

```
Fresco.initialize(applicationContext)
```

And in finish, use it.

**XML:**

```
 <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
  android:id="@+id/avatar"
  android:layout_width="110dp"
  android:layout_height="110dp" />
```

**Java:**

```
avatar.setImageURI(user.getAvatarUrl())
```