# setImageResource() no image showing up

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, bitmapfactory

I have an adapter which displays contact information. If a contact has a photo, it gets displayed, else the `ic_launcher` image is set as image

```
 if (contact.photoUri != null)
        holder.imageView.setImageURI(contact.photoUri);
    else
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

`setImageUri` works fine, but `setImageResource()`, `setBackgroundResource()` and `setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))` are not displaying anything.

There is an error which I can´t reproduce, because this image works quite well on some other adapters of mine:

```
BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /null: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
System.out﹕ resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: null
```

What is happening?

EDIT:

Even accessing the image via uri doesn´t work. it acts as the image does not exist :(

2.EDIT:

Now I´ve preset a default image via xml, but it isn´t working too!

Comment: so tell me does holder.imageView.setImageURI(contact.photoUri) works for you or not?

Comment: ENOENT is your answer - you have one more step to do ...

Comment: and what is the step?

Comment: Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738192/how-to-get-contact-photo-uri and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870638/how-to-use-setimageuri-on-android