# Jsoup Android, imageView and src

Tags: java, android, image, imageview, jsoup

I have a problem ...
I want to change an image (ImageView). I capture the image from a website.
On this page there is more than one image.
I want to select the URL, and I change it.

```j
Elements image;
       image = document.select("img");
       String PhotoSrc = image.attr("src");
    // OR
Elements castsImageUrl = document.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");
                imgSrc = castsImageUrl.first().attr("src");
```

I do not select the url I want. I do not know how I can do it.
When I have the URL, as I change my R.id.Photo?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to explain just what URL *does* get selected. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to get an image using Jsoup and pass to an ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612629/how-to-get-an-image-using-jsoup-and-pass-to-an-imageview)

or use Picasso library

http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-use-picasso-library-in-android