# Issue with setImageResource() - how can I implement file path?

Tags: java, android

I am not able to find out how to set a picture as `setImageResource()`. Currently I can easily add from `res/drawable` like this:

In ListViewAdapter:

```
imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listImageView); 
    imageView.setImageResource((int) getItemId(position));
```

In ViewAdapter:

```
public class ViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
    class Item { 
        public long id;
        public String name; 

    public Item(long id, String name) { 
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name; 
    } 
} 
public ViewAdapter(Context c) { 
    mContext = c; 

    mItems = new ArrayList<Item>();

    mItems.add(new Item(R.drawable.mercury,"Mercury")); 
    mItems.add(new Item(R.drawable.mercury,"Mercury")); 
    mItems.add(new Item(R.drawable.mercury,"Mercury")); ...
```

So, how can I add a picture from a path? For example, say `"/storage/emulated/Photos/Italy.jpg"`? Again, I can store them in `res/drawable` and add them, but need a way to add it from file. Tried different ways, but still can't find out how to do it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File imgFile = new  File(“/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg”);

if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
setImageURI(Uri uri)
```

see this :

[How to use setImageUri() on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870638/how-to-use-setimageuri-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
imagView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set picture from path

```
    File img = new  File("here your path"");
    if(img.exists()){

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img.getAbsolutePath());

        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

  }
```