# How to use setImageURI() in android?

Tags: android, android-imageview, imageurl

I tried

```
imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Uri photoUrl = profile1.getPhotoUrl();
imageView.setImageURI(photoUrl);
```

But i dont see anything.
I am getting url when i am printing it
Thanks in advance

Comment: try to print value of photoURL

Comment: I am getting url when i am printing it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23865531/4601170

Comment: try chopping the extra arguments off the end (after the .jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use setImageUri() on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870638/how-to-use-setimageuri-on-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `picasso` for this:

```
 Picasso.with(context)
           .load(url)
           .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
           .resize(imgWidth, imgHeight)
           .centerCrop()
           .into(image);
```

Comment: Same behavior / code with Glide (https://github.com/bumptech/glide) which which is promoted by Google. See the Paris DroidCon 2016 conference : https://youtu.be/04igNM9IpwE?t=33m26s comparing Picasso and Glide.

Comment: Yeah.. I heard a lot about glide. but did not use it.. I am planning to use this in my next assigment

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL("YOUR_URL").getContent());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```